# How can I call different Fields from one Django models to another fields of another Django Field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, reference

I want to call MemberRegistration Model's 'fname' and 'regino' fields to TypeCharge Model (in 'serial' field), and 'fname' and 'presentaddress' fields to BankAccount Model (in 'accholder' field). I tried Foreign Key but it can only return one combination at a time due to def **str**(self). Thank You..!

Here are my models:

````
`class MemberRegistration(models.Model):
    regino = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=user_id)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    presentaddress = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.regino) + " - " + self.fname

class TypeCharge(models.Model):
    serial = models.ForeignKey(MemberRegistration, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    chargename = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class BankAccount(models.Model):
    accholder = models.ForeignKey(MemberRegistration, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separated method for each call in `MemberRegistration` model and call it on your `BankAccount` or `TypeCharge` like that:

models.py:

```
class MemberRegistration(models.Model):
    regino = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=user_id)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    presentaddress = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.regino) + " - " + self.fname

    def from_type_charge(self):
        return str(self.regino) + " - " + self.fname

    def from_bank_account(self):
        return self.presentaddress + " - " + self.fname

class TypeCharge(models.Model):
    serial = models.ForeignKey(MemberRegistration,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    chargename = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class BankAccount(models.Model):
    accholder = models.ForeignKey(MemberRegistration, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

anywhere else:

```
type_charge = TypeCharge.objects.first() # get an instance of TypeCharge
print(type_charge.serial.from_type_charge())

bank_account = BankAccount.objects.first() # get an instance of BankAccount
print(bank_account.accholder.from_bank_account())
```

or you can do like this:

```
type_charge = TypeCharge.objects.first() # get an instance of TypeCharge
print(type_charge.serial.fname + " - " + type_charge.serial.regino)

bank_account = BankAccount.objects.first() # get an instance of BankAccount
print(bank_account.accholder.fname + " - " + bank_account.accholder.presentaddress)
```